# Failed to construct 'WebSocket': The URL '{{.}}' is invalid

Tags: javascript, websocket, gorilla

#### `gorilla/websocket` example

In this example:

https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/e8629af678b7fe13f35dff5e197de93b4148a909/examples/echo/server.go#L79

The WebSocket is created by:

```
ws = new WebSocket("{{.}}");
```

The example works fine.

#### Problem

But, then I want to use the same code in another JS code like:

```js
var ws;
ws = new WebSocket("{{.}}");
ws.onopen = function(evt) {
    console.log("OPEN SOCKET");
}
ws.onclose = function(evt) {
    console.log("CLOSE SOCKET");
    ws = null;
}
ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
    console.log("RESPONSE SOCKET: RECEIVED");
}
ws.onerror = function(evt) {
    console.log("ERROR: " + evt.data);
}
ws.send(positions);
ws.close();
```

I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': The URL '{{.}}' is invalid.
> at AddObjectCommand.execute

I changed WebSocket like this:

```js
ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8080/echo");
```

But I'm still getting an error:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8080/echo' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403

I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. What did I miss?

#### Fix `403`

The `403` error got resolved by this suggestion:

https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/issues/367#issuecomment-375971418

By adding:

```golang
upgrader.CheckOrigin = func(r *http.Request) bool { return true }
```

Before:

```golang
c, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
```

It's not safe to trust all origins, of course. Just a temporary fix.

#### Yet another error

But another error is thrown:

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error of:

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.

Got resolved by sending data through WebSocket, by its `.onopen` callback:

```
var positions = ...

var ws;
ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8080/echo");
ws.onopen = function(evt) {
    console.log("OPEN SOCKET");
    console.log("SEND: START");
    ws.send(positions);
    ws.close();
}
```

Comment: This is not Go code. Why did you tag it with [tag:go] at all?